# Div not aligning properly

Tags: css, width, division

I have the following alignment problem: I want the "random" div to have a full width in the window, that's why I added the "width:100%" command. But for some reason, the maximum width it displays the random div on is the width of the "fixedwidth" div, but the two are not connected. Why does the browser keep matching the maximum width of the two divs? If i increase the width of the "fixedwitdth" div, then the width of the "random div" also increases. But that does not make any sense.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Gliga's BBC</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    margin:0px;
    font-family: arial,helvetica;
}

#topbar {
    background-color:#7A0000;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    color:white;

}

.fixedwidth {
    width:1200px;
    background-color:green;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#logodiv {

    padding-top:7px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-left:50px;
    float:left;
    border-right: 2px solid #990000;
    padding-right:30px;
}

#signindiv {
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:9px 80px 11px 20px;
    font-size:0.9 em;
    float:left;
    border-right: 2px solid #990000;


}

#topmenudiv {
    float:left;
}

#topmenudiv ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#topmenudiv li {
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:0.9 em;
    border-right: 2px solid #990000;
    height:100%;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    float:left;
}

#searchdiv { 
    float:left;
    padding:6px 10px 5px; 5px;
    border-right: 2px solid #990000;
}

#searchdiv input{ 
    height:20px;
}

.break {
    clear: both;

}



.random {
    background-color:blue;
    margin-top:10px;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="topbar">

    <div class="fixedwidth">

        <div id="logodiv">
            <img src="images/bbclogo.png"/>
        </div>

        <div id="signindiv">
                                   Sign in
        </div>

        <div id="topmenudiv">
                                  <ul>
                                  <li>News</li>
                                  <li>Sport</li> 
                                  <li>Weather</li>
                                  <li>iPLayer</li>
                                  <li>TV</li>
                                  <li>Radio</li>
                                  <li>More...</li>
        </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="searchdiv">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />

        <div>



    </div>


</div>

<div class="break" />

<div class="random">

</div>


</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to fix your tag nesting. `.random` is inside `.fixedwidth`. `DIV`s cannot self close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.random` is a child of `.fixedwidth`, so it's a totally normal behaviour happening there.

If you **sort your code properly** then you will get to see it clearly:

[image]